# Help in Deployment C# and SQL SERVER 2005 PROJECT

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, deployment-project

I have created a project using C# and SQL SERVER 2005.

I want to deploy the project so that I can create .msi file.

Can anyone help me with the steps I should follow to create the setup file?

Also in which editor I should add then database and how can I add it?

Please somebody help me out!

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c%28VS.71%29.aspx

You cannot embed database into setup. That needs to be installed separately.

You may also find [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264562%28SQL.90%29.aspx) useful